# PHP cron calls causing incorrect data

Tags: php, api, cron

I've got an interesting question; I fetch data from an external provider, for the sake of completeness, let's say it comes back like this:

```
[
    [id: 1pm, item_a: 55, item_b: 180], // hour's passed so data is finished.
    [id: 2pm, item_a: 55, item_b: 180], // hour's passed so data is finished.
    [id: 3pm, item_a: 55, item_b: 180], // hour's passed so data is finished.
    [id: 4pm, item_a: 55, item_b: 180], // hour's passed so data is finished.
    [id: 5pm, item_a: 0, item_b: 0], // current hour - data keeps updating periodically
]
```

I run a cron call hourly to fetch the latest hour's element (*i.e. `5pm` in the group above*).

Note how the initial value for `item_a` & `item_b` are 0. That is because the data coming in for the hour is constantly being updated from the third-party. This **is not on a set time period**, which makes it hard for me to gather the data accurately. As I'm fetching data for ~1400 different objects, they are each updated at random intervals on the third parties end which leaves me with incorrect data once the hour is up.

I currently run a cron job every 15 minutes to an internal php script that does the following;

- fetches the most recent row
- checks against the third party API
- If the `item_a` or `item_b` are different -> we update all rows
- If not, the script exits itself.

---

```
*/15 * * * * curl my-website.com/api/path-to-update?access_key=my_access_key
```

---

This results in the data being a) delayed, and b) occasionally less that what it should be.

Would I need to set up something like RabbitMQ to handle the constant streaming of data/checks/etc?

Comment: Maybe the API call and updating of your local data takes some time to update, or some calls to the API are too slow to respond synchronously. Try: http://docs.guzzlephp.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate call that runs a final check for the "hours" worth of data 15 minutes into the next hour.

So the calls ended up being;

```
$Api->data_fetch_new_hour();
$Api->data_update_currency_hour();
$Api->data_update_previous_hour();
```

All run on separate cron jobs.